# how to continue flow after amqp:outbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a way to continue a spring integration flow after publishing message using amqp:outbound-channel-adapter?
- using confirm-ack-channel, i can continue the flow only after amqp ack which takes too long. I am trying to see if i dont care about acks, if I can continue the flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use something like `PublishSubscribeChannel`, when you can have more subscribers, not only one `<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>`. Another approach can be done with the `RecipientListRouter`, when you send the same message to several channels at once.

One more trick can be done with the `WireTap` pattern, where you send the same message to different channel during process to the `<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

And there is one more secret - `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with its `successChannel` as a part of the `<request-handler-advice-chain>` in the `<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>` configuration.

Everything that you can find in the Reference Manual.